# Unable to find Custom Style

Tags: android, xml

one of my xml Files does not find the attributes definied in a style.
I think the style is correct, as it works with other Files.
Not a single style does work. It says i need to define the layout_width and layout_height attributes, but I did so in the style.

I think it's simpler to give you just one example. If you need the whole xml file, this is no problem.

```
<RelativeLayout
    style="@style/relativeLayout_multiplechoicefrage_aufloesung_content" >

<style name="relativeLayout_multiplechoicefrage_aufloesung_content">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/frage_content_marginLeft</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">@dimen/frage_content_marginRight</item>
</style>
```

I already cleaned the project, but this didn't work.

Hopefully anyone can find a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Did you define the style in the same file as your layout (your example suggests that)? I think you've to put your style in the res/values folder like this:

**res/values/styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="relativeLayout_multiplechoicefrage_aufloesung_content">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/frage_content_marginLeft</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">@dimen/frage_content_marginRight</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Then you should be able to reference it just like your code example does right now.

Comment: Yes, it is in this file.
As i mentioned, the same style works in other layout files.